# Refreshing the JPanel or Closing and Opening Again

Tags: java, swing, refresh, jpanel, layout-manager

I'm writing a simple slide program. In that program, I show small thumbnails of all slides in a new jpanel. In that new jpanel, after clicking 2 thumbnails, it should swap them. However, after swaping them, jpanel is not refreshing. If I create new jpanel by calling createAndShowGUI() function, it is ok, but then I need to close the old jpanel.

Below is my simple class,

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/GridLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/GridLayoutDemo.java

And in my main program if I click "slide sorter mode" button handler compile the following code

gridLayoutDemoObject.createAndShowGUI();

What is the solution and how should I make it ?

Thanks.

Comment: You should post some code of how you are swapping the images. Maybe you need to call refresh().

Comment: Actually I'm not swapping the images, I have a class called slides, and each slide object has different kind of objects such as line rectangle ellipse and etc. Therefore, in actionlistener of my jframe keeps track of my clicks, and with respect to that, it swaps in my main program. Swapping is correct, because I can see the change in my main screen, however I cannot see that change in new opened window which has all thumbnails

Answer (score 3):

You didn't provide enough information to indicate how you display the images or how you swap them so its hard to give a proper answer.

I would display the images by using a JLabel (or JButton without a Border). Then when you can just use `setIcon(...)` to swap icons and the label will repaint itself.

Next time post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem so we don't have to guess what you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry, thats right, I'm displaying all slide icons with button by using very similar to this code http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/GridLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/GridLayoutDemo.java

Comment: @CanCeylan: so did camickr's good suggestion (to swap ImageIcons) solve your problem? If so accept it. If not, at least up-vote it (I have) and create and post your SSCCE and a more detailed explanation of the specific problem.

Comment: @camickr, I firstly added created all buttons into an arraylist, I swapped then with the following method, 

JButton dummy = butonlar.get(y); butonlar.set(y, butonlar.get(x)); butonlar.set(x, dummy); repaint(); 

(butonlar is my arraylist)

in my actual program, slides are swapping however there is no change in my slidesorter window

Comment: @CanCeylan: you're still not giving us nearly enough information to have the faintest clue as to what's wrong, and you're still not showing offending code or an SSCCE despite multiple requests -- why?

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing. Swapping buttons in an ArrayList has nothing to do with a GUI.